# how to print document directly in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used below code to print document directly in C# winform

```
string fileName = @"D:\filename11" + ext; //  Here ext is file extension
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.DocumentName = fileName;
printDoc.Print();
```

this code does not works, prints blank page. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.documentname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The DocumentName property **does not specify the file to print**. Rather, you specify the output to print by handling the PrintPage event. For an example, see [the PrintDocument class overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).